# Is there a way to prevent NVIDIA driver from binding to secondary or tertiary gpus?

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

On Linux, I am using three NVIDIA GPUs. When I install and load the NVIDIA driver into the kernel, the driver is automatically binding to all three GPUs.

I am trying to prevent the NVIDIA driver from automatically binding to two of my NVIDIA GPUs when the driver is loaded into the Linux kernel.

Is there a way to either allow the driver to bind only to the specified GPU or block the driver from automatically binding to the specified GPUs?

I do not want two of my three GPUs not bound to any drivers at all.

Comment: What’s your specific use case? Passing the GPUs to VMs? I believe there is a device blacklist in Linux, defined on the kernel command line.